# PHP installation error on Centos 6.7 (libmcrypt)

Tags: php, vagrant, centos6

Configured with

PHP    5.6

Mysql  5.6..x

Nginx  1.8.x

CentOS 6.7

When I run yum install php-mcrypt , I get the error

```
Error: Package: php55w-mcrypt-5.5.38-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
       Requires: libmcrypt.so.4()(64bit)
```

I have tried copying over the file (libmcrypt) into lib64 but it doesn't show up either. Not sure why, I am using

```
sudo cp /home/vagrant/lib-files/libmcrypt.so.4 /usr/lib64/
```

And when I check my lib64, still nothing.

I have also tried this. 
I have also tried this and gotten this output. Still not working.

```
sudo yum install php-mcrypt
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: mirror.pac-12.org
 extras: centos.mirrors.my2pro.com
* updates: mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu
* webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php56w-mcrypt.x86_64 0:5.6.30-1.w6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmcrypt.so.4()(64bit) for package:      php56w-mcrypt-5.6.30-1.w6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php56w-mcrypt-5.6.30-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
       Requires: libmcrypt.so.4()(64bit)
```

Comment: I have also tried this and gotten this output. Still not working.

Comment: Is this the PHP version provided by Centos/6.7 or some third-party package?

Comment: i believe it's provided by Centos @ÁlvaroGonzález

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment so I'll answer hope it'll help:

In my case before (which we basically have the same setup, CentOS, PHP MySQL)

```
yum -y update
rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm
yum install php56w php56w-opcache -y
yum install -y php56w-mcrypt
```

Please try this one. You may skip the update to latest OS.

Comment: Thx bro, this pakage <b>rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm</b> helped right